# How to mount the usb stick with old raspbian?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, raspberry-pi, ext4, raspbian

I have cloned my SD card content (old Raspbian used on Raspberry Pi 2) with Win32diskimager to the USB stick. Then I have booted my new raspberry Pi 3 with a new freshly on SD card installed Raspbian. Now I would like to copy the user data from my old system (cloned to usb disk) into the new system.

I inserted into raspberry pi 3 the both devices SD Card and USB Stick. After booting, I could mount SDA1 as VFAT partition. There I could see some files, which I was also able to see in windows (I think it was NOOBS installation), but I can not find the EXT4 partition (in a list of partitions) with my old Raspbian.

What should I do to copy my user data from old Raspbian into new Raspbian?

Comment: Did you need to use windows to copy your data from the USB , or using ubuntu?

Comment: I can use all three operating systems: Raspbian, Windows, ubuntu. But it would be better to achieve it with Raspbian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to mount the usb stick with old raspbian?

Under linux system you can mount an external drive as follows:

Use the command `sudo fdisk -l` to check the partition (e,g `sdb`= your USB)

Create a mount point :

```
mkdir /mnt/my_usb
```

Mount your usb:

```
sudo mount /dev/sdb/mnt/my_usb
```

Change direcory to `/mnt/my_usb` , you will find your data

Comment: I have already done it. But after that I can see only VFAT partition of USB stick with NOOBS files. I cannot find EXT4 partition with my old Raspbian :(

Comment: Please add the output of `fdisk -l`

Comment: sorry, was my mistake, I used "fdisk -l" without "sudo", and there was no information about my devices... Now I mounted my usb stick successfully. Thanks